# QGIS c++ Reset feature id

Tags: c++, qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to add / Update / Delete features in a QgsVectorLayer in QGIS.

I'm using this code:

```
QgsFeatureIds FeatureIds=PointLayer->allFeatureIds();

if (FeatureIds.contains(Id.toInt())) {
    QgsFeature feature=PointLayer->getFeature(Id.toInt());
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry::fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(longitude,latitude)));
    PointLayer->updateFeature(feature);
} else {
    QgsFeature feature;
    feature.setId(Id.toInt());
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry::fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(longitude,latitude)));
    PointLayer->dataProvider()->addFeature(feature);
}
```

and for clearing the layer

```
PointLayer->dataProvider()->trucate()
```

Note: I will truncate if the data gets overcrowded that's why I am using truncate().

Initially while adding the features using

```
PointLayer->dataProvider()->addFeature(feature);
```

the feature id which I pass is same even after addFeature is called
Now after truncating, if I want to add feature then its feature id changes

i.e
if I call this code:

```
PointLayer->dataProvider()->addFeature(feature);
```

The id looking as if it's an auto-increment number.

How to reset the Id of the feature so that what ever I pass stays
which is happening initially.

If solution is available in pyqgis also is ok for me.